# Hide value in JAVAScript modal pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal

```
<select onchange="SUGAR.email2.composeLayout.applyEmailTemplate('0', 
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="email_template0" name="email_template0">

<option value="">-none-</option>
<option value="159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328">Case Closure</option>
<option value="182641ab-44c0-719d-04b3-52fdffa2b2d2">Case Creation</option>
</select>
```

I have this java modal pop-up. I would like to hide certain values i.e. 159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328. Incidentally these are **drop-down** values.

I've tried this but it don't work.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
$("#email_template0 option[value='159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328']").hide();
});
```

Any pointer please.
Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: this doesn't seems to be JAVA, are using any framework ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide? Is to hide the item with that value from the dropdown ?

Comment: What do you mean by hide these values? these values are anyway not visible in the dropdown.

Comment: Open console and type `$("#email_template0 option[value='159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328']").hide();` and see if dropdown menu is hiding.

Comment: http://f.cl.ly/items/3T382J1t0e0x3n0U3W2C/modal.png
I guess the screen-shot will make things clearer.

Comment: If I give this:

    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0',
    function(event) {
    $('#email_template0').hide();
    });

I am able to hide the entire "Template" drop-down. However I need to hide values inside the drop-down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. If I run this command in console, then the value is hidden.

    $("#email_template0 option[value='159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328']").hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct method

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
```

Instead of this

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
```

In addition I am also able to hide/show based on other element values like this.

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
    if ($('#data_parent_type0').val() == 'Leads') {
    $("#email_template0 option[value='159a06ef-4d58-6eff-a969-52fdff05d328']").hide();
    }
});
```

Thanks to pointers from Ritesh.